# Найти алгоритм подсчета количеств множественного перекрытия интервалов, а также найти длительность таких интервалов

Tags: python

Условия задачи:

- Ограничение времени, с   2
- Ограничение памяти, МБ   96
- Общее число попыток отправки 15

Петя решил узнать, когда программисту выгоднее всего искать работу на hh.ru. Конечно, когда больше всего открыто вакансий.

Он выгрузил в текстовый файл время открытия и закрытия всех подходящих вакансий за 2019 год.

Теперь нужно определить период времени, когда открытых вакансий было больше всего.

Считаем, что:

- начальное и конечное время всегда присутствуют;
- начальное время всегда меньше или равно конечному;
- начальное и конечное время включены в интервал.

Входные данные
Входная информация поступает из стандартного ввода, в первой строке приходит 1 число - количество вакансий. Каждая из следующих строк содержит информацию о вакансии в виде двух чисел – начальное и конечное время, они разделены пробелом. Время задается в секундах ([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)). Некорректные данные на вход не поступают, дополнительные проверки не требуются.

Выходные данные
В качестве ответа в стандартный вывод через пробел нужно вывести два числа: количество найденных интервалов и сумму длительности интервалов в секундах (начальная и конечная секунды должны быть включены в интервал).

```
Пример 1
Входные данные:

1
1595862781 1595862785
Выходные данные: 1 5


Пример 2
Входные данные:

2
1595862781 1595862783
1595862782 1595862784
Выходные данные: 1 2


Пример 3
Входные данные:

2
1595862781 1595862782
1595862783 1595862784
Выходные данные: 2 4
```

Вот мой код. Тесты из примеров проходит но на закрытых данных где-то дает не правильный ответ.

```
def count_intervals(intervals):
    
    list_to_check = []
    for interval in intervals:
        list_to_check.append([interval[0],1])
        list_to_check.append([interval[1],-1])
    list_to_check.sort()
    
    count_interval = 0
    
    job_count = 0
    job_count_was = 0
    start_interval = False
    
    sum_duration = 0
    
    for i, interval in enumerate(list_to_check):
        
        job_count_was = job_count
        job_count += interval[1]
        
        if start_interval == True and job_count < job_count_was:
            sum_duration += interval[0] - list_to_check[i-1][0] + 1
            count_interval += 1
            start_interval = False
        elif job_count > job_count_was:
            start_interval = True
            
    return [count_interval , sum_duration]
    
      
input_intervals = int(input())
intervals = []
while input_intervals > 0:
    input_intervals -= 1
    interval_start, interval_end = input().split()
    interval_start = int(interval_start)
    interval_end = int(interval_end)
    intervals.append([interval_start, interval_end])


resault_intervals = count_intervals(intervals)

print(resault_intervals[0], resault_intervals[1])
```

Comment: Дайте нормальный заголовок вопросу

Comment: При тесте на данных **5; 1 5; 3 7; 5 9; 6 7; 2 2;** ваш код выдает **2 4**.
На сколько я понимаю, ответ должен быть **3 4**.
П.С. к сожалению не могу оставить комментарий, так как меньше 50 баллов.

Comment: @Pavel Dubrov Ответ должен быть 2 3. Спасибо, благодаря Вам заметил в ответе ошибку (время не обнулялось)

Comment: @Ярославцев Андрей можете описать подробный алгоритм решения задачи словами и почему возникали трудности, что не проходило?спасибо

Comment: @Prog44 заносим в список все начала и концы интервала с разметкой конца и начала. Начало -1, конец 1, назовем это флаг начала и флаг конца. Либо можно начало 0, конец 1. Сортируем список по возрастанию. Проходим по списку проверяя, если флаг начала добавляем к счетчику интервалов и проверяем больше ли максимума этот счетчик, если больше присваиваем новый максимум и обнуляем счетчики времени и интервалов с максимум вакансий, если равен то обновляем счетчик интервалов и старт максимального интервала. Если флаг конца интервала, проверяем счетчик интервалов на равенство максимуму и обновляем длит.

Comment: @Prog44 не проходило сначала у меня потому, что я пытался считать все интервалы, только пересечения считал за один интервал. Трудности из-за не очень для меня понятной формулировки задачи, в плане формулировки выходных данных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то запутано всё с образованием новых интервалов. С многократным перекрытием работает?

Есть такой алгоритм (со сложностью O(nlogn) за счёт сортировки):

Занести в список для всех начал и концов пары, состоящие из времени и поля признака -1 для конца, +1 для начала.

Отсортировать по времени

Пройти по списку, добавляя значение поля +-1 к счётчику активных интервалов.

Если счётчик уменьшается, сравнить его с максимумом, и при превышении заменить максимум и обновить суммарное время, при равенстве добавить последний промежуток (от момента роста счётчика) к суммарному времени

```
input_intervals = int(input())
points = []
while input_intervals > 0:
    input_intervals -= 1
    interval_start, interval_end = input().split()
    interval_start = int(interval_start)
    interval_end = int(interval_end)
    points.append([interval_start, -1])  # начало делаем -1 для нужной сортировки
    points.append([interval_end, 1])

points.sort()
#print(points)

maxvac = 0
maxvacnum = 0
maxvactime = 0
count = 0
for p in points:
    if p[1] < 0:  #начало
        count += 1
        if count > maxvac:   #всё обнуляем
            maxvac = count
            maxvacnum = 1
            maxstart = p[0]
            maxvactime = 0
        elif count == maxvac:
            maxvacnum += 1   #обновляем количество лучших
            maxstart = p[0]
    else:
        if count == maxvac:  # конец интервала с лучшим пока набором
            maxvactime += p[0] - maxstart + 1
        count -=1

print(maxvacnum, maxvactime)
```

Comment: Если мы встретили -1, то интервал заканчивается. В этот момент можно проверить текущий счётчик (количество вакансий). Если он больше максимума, то станет новым максимумом и время заменить на длину заканчивающегося интервала, а если равен - то просто добавить длину этого интервала.

Comment: Спасибо! Это же алгоритм "метод сканирующей прямой"? Только там нужно вроде как не вакансии посчитать, а количество интервалов. То есть пересекающиеся интервалы нужно убрать таким образом: как я понял взять интервалы на которых одна и более вакансий открыто судя по второму примеру. Там получается 2 вакансии, оставляем только интервал, где открыты 2 вакансии одновременно. Как найти интервал с максимальным количеством вакансий с помощью этого алгоритма я понял.

Comment: Переписал, используя этот алгоритм, но для подсчета интервалов. Поправил в вопросе. Все равно какой-то случай перекрытия видимо не учитываю.

Comment: Привел код с реализацией того, что я написал. Примеры проходят, для `3;  1 5; 2 4; 4 6` даёт `1 1` - тройное перекрытие на 4 секунде

Comment: Спасибо! Понял Ваш код и решение, осознал, что я не понял задачу видимо. Правда, к сожалению, и это решение не проходит на закрытых данных.

Comment: Меня несколько смущает `начальное и конечное время включены в интервал` - что будет для интервалов 1 2 и 2 3 - перекрытие на 1 секунду? У меня сделано так, но вдруг они чего другое имели в виду? (А примера не дали)

Comment: @Ярославцев Андрей Ошибку исправил

Comment: Да, вот тоже интересно, вроде если включается и конец и начало должно быть перекрытие на 1 секунду. Я вот не сразу понял, что нужно посчитать интервалы именно лучших, где больше всего вакансий. Но по второму примеру выходит, что только лучшие, потому что там по факту 3 интервала. Я сначала думал что просто, где есть перекрытия считать как один интервал.