# Какой алгоритм использовать для поиска точки, охватывающей наибольшее количество интервалов, и вычислить время этой точки

Tags: python

Входная информация поступает из стандартного ввода, в первой строке приходит 1 число - количество вакансий. Каждая из следующих строк содержит информацию о вакансии в виде двух чисел – начальное и конечное время, они разделены пробелом. Некорректные данные на вход не поступают.

Теперь нужно определить период времени, когда открытых вакансий было больше всего.

Считаем, что:

- начальное и конечное время всегда присутствуют;
- начальное время всегда меньше или равно конечному;
- начальное и конечное время включены в интервал.

Выходные данные

В качестве ответа в стандартный вывод через пробел нужно вывести два числа: количество найденных интервалов и сумму длительности интервалов в секундах (начальная и конечная секунды должны быть включены в интервал).

Пример 1

Исходные данные: 1

1595862781 1595862785

Выходные данные: 1 5

Пример 2

Входные данные:

2

1595862781 1595862783

1595862782 1595862784

Выходные данные: 1 2

Пример 3

Входные данные:

2

1595862781 1595862782

1595862783 1595862784

Выходные данные: 2 4

Решил методом «Сканирующая прямая», но решение не проходит все тесты. Вот пример кода. Создал список с временными интервалами, отсортировал его, когда встречаем "старт" увеличиваем счетчик вакансий и сверяем с максимальным количеством вакансий, если больше устанавливаем время начала интервала, если меньше устанавливаем время конца, считаем период и добавляем в список количество вакансий и период. Какие методы актуальны для этой задачи? На каких тестах может упасть решение?

```
def final():
    i = 0
    times = []
    ans = []
    val = int(input())
    while i < val:
        start, end = input().split()
        times.append((start,  0) )
        times.append((end, 1))
        i += 1
    times = sorted(times)
    
    
    vacancy = 0
    maxVacancy= 0
    timeStart = 0
    timeEnd = 0
    period = 0

    for time in times:
        if time[1] == 0:
            vacancy += 1
            if vacancy > maxVacancy:
                timeStart = int(time[0])
                timeEnd = -1
                maxVacancy = vacancy
        else:
            vacancy -= 1
            if vacancy < maxVacancy and timeEnd == -1:
                timeEnd = int(time[0])
                period = timeEnd - timeStart + 1
                ans.append((maxVacancy, period))
                maxVacancy = vacancy

    max = ans[0][0]
    time = 0
    span = 0
    for val in ans:
        if val[0] > max:
            max = val[0]
            time = val[1]
            span = 1
        elif val[0] == max:
            time += val[1]
            span += 1
    print(span, time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    final()
```

Comment: А код чего убрал? Кому-то может пригодиться -так что стоит поправить ошибку и вставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сортировка битая. У тебя вместо чисел лежат строки и сортируются они не по возрастанию, а лексикографически.

https://ideone.com/iLHmnU

```
2
2 10
5 6
```

```
[('10', 'zend'), ('2', 'start'), ('5', 'start'), ('6', 'zend')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Идея решения правильная.

Чтобы не запутаться, действия стоит выполнять сразу при изменении счётчика, т.е.

```
    if time[1] == 'start':
        count += 1
        действия при увеличении (if count >= maxCount: ...
    else:
        действия при уменьшении (if count == maxCount: ...
        count -= 1
```

и после этого цикла вообще ничего не придётся делать.

Код приведу, как [в параллельном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166923/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/1166953?noredirect=1#comment2029128_1166953)

```
input_intervals = int(input())
points = []
while input_intervals > 0:
    input_intervals -= 1
    interval_start, interval_end = input().split()
    interval_start = int(interval_start)
    interval_end = int(interval_end)
    points.append([interval_start, -1])  # начало делаем -1 для нужной сортировки
    points.append([interval_end, 1])

points.sort()
#print(points)

maxvac = 0
maxvacnum = 0
maxvactime = 0
count = 0
for p in points:
    if p[1] < 0:  #начало
        count += 1
        if count > maxvac:   #всё обнуляем
            maxvac = count
            maxvacnum = 1
            maxstart = p[0]
            maxvactime = 0
        elif count == maxvac:
            maxvacnum += 1   #обновляем количество лучших
            maxstart = p[0]
    else:
        if count == maxvac:  # конец интервала с лучшим пока набором
            maxvactime += p[0] - maxstart + 1
        count -=1

print(maxvacnum, maxvactime)
```

Comment: При равенстве начало должно быть раньше конца, в не наоборот.

Comment: Ааа, `начальное и конечное время включены в интервал.` означает, что если один кончается в 10, а второй начинается в 10, то ровно в 10 активны оба интервала... Тогда да, начала раньше. Ну я вижу, что Qwertiy нашёл прокол.со строками вместо чисел.

Answer (score 0):

(не хватает репутации, чтобы оставить в качестве комментария)

Дополню ответ Qwertiy.

Преобразовать строки в числа, так:

```
times.append((int(start),  'start') )
times.append((int(end), 'zend'))
```

На примере JS'a сортировка выглядит, так:

```
    times.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[0] > b[0]) {
            return +1
        } else if (a[0] < b[0]) {
            return -1
        } else if (a[0] === b[0] && a[1] === 'start') {
            return -1
        } else if (a[0] === b[0]) {
            return +1
        }
        
        return 0
    })
```

Сори, на Пайтон мало пишу :)